# Avoid duplicate values in Collection

Tags: vb6

I have following values, and I want to add these to a collection. If the values are already in the collection, a message should show "this is already added in your collection".

```
Dim OrdLines As New Collection

OrdLines.Add (111,this is first item)

OrdLines.Add (222,this is second item)

OrdLines.Add (333,this is third item)

OrdLines.Add (444,this is fourth item)
```

How do I avoid duplicate values in a collection?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To avoid duplicates `without any prompts` use this method.

**Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim itm

    On Error Resume Next
    col.Add 111, Cstr(111)
    col.Add 222, Cstr(222)
    col.Add 111, Cstr(111)
    col.Add 111, Cstr(111)
    col.Add 333, Cstr(333)
    col.Add 111, Cstr(111)
    col.Add 444, Cstr(444)
    col.Add 555, Cstr(555)
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each itm In col
        Debug.Print itm
    Next
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

**Explanation**

A collection is an ordered set of items that you can refer to as a unit. The syntax is

```
col.Add item, key, before, after
```

A collection cannot have the same key twice so what we are doing is creating a key using the item that we are adding. This will ensure that we will not get duplicates. The `On Error Resume Next` is just telling the code to ignore the error we get when we try to add a duplicate and simply move on to the next item to add. The `CHR(34)` is nothing but `"` so the above statement can also be written as

```
col.Add 111, """" & 111 & """"
```

**Suggested Read**

[The Visual Basic Collection Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231021%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

HTH

Comment: What is the point of using `Chr(34)` or `""""` at all?  Why not just wrap it around with `CStr()`?

Comment: @PhoenixX_2: Yup you have a point, it completely skipped my mind :)

Answer (score 8):

This is one of those scenarios where a Dictionary offers some advantages.

```
Option Explicit

'Requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Private Sub Main()
    Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary 'As New XXX adds overhead.
    Dim Item As Variant

    Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With Dict
        .Item(111) = 111
        .Item(222) = 222
        .Item(111) = 111
        .Item(111) = 111
        .Item(333) = 333
        .Item(111) = 111
        .Item(222) = 222
        .Item(333) = 333

        For Each Item In .Items
            Debug.Print Item
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting dictionaries. I think a lot of people just aren't aware of them or how to use them.   This is a great way to use them though,  as the initial call creates the item if it didn't exist and subsequent calls to the same item just overwrite it. You don't even need to use the `.add` method. Nice work!

Answer (score -1):

Use the `Add` method along with key.

Syntax:

```
OrderLines.Add(ObjectToAdd, Key)
```

Remember key is a string.

Example:

```
OrdLines.Add(222,"222")
OrdLines.Add(222,"333")
OrdLines.Add(222,"444")

OrdLines.Add(222,"222") 'This will give error
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a [built in method that allows you check for duplicates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172935%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), assuming you *are* always assigning a `Key` value. This is preferably than `On Error Resume Next`.

```
If Not OrdLines.Contains(key_value) Then
    OrdLines.Add(item_value, key_value, before, after)
End If
```

**NOTE** This is VB.NET, not VBA/VB6.  In VBA/VB6 you could write a custom function similar to [the approach given, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651/check-if-a-record-exists-in-a-vb6-collection).

Comment: That is for VB.NET and not for VB6/VBA.

Comment: @PhoenixX_2  syntax is the same. I use this method in VBA all the time. It's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: But now I've gone and changed my link (thinking you though it *should* have been a link to VB.NET) and now I lost the old URL, so yeah, now the URL is pointing to VB.NET, but in any case the method and its syntax are the same.

Comment: I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method." error.  I wish what you were saying was true, because I'm using `On Error Resume Next` as well in my projects :(.

Comment: Ahhh you're totally right I must have been thinking of `dictionary.Exists` method... I recently wrote a UDF to replicate this method on vector arrays, and I think I may have done that also for `Collection` objects, too so that must have been what I was thinking about. Thanks for setting me straight :)

Comment: I removed the -1, but someone else put another one in.  Ugh, this site is pretty lame sometimes.

Comment: @PhoenixX_2 no worries!