# Unique values in combobox in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get the unique values in combobox 2 once I select from combobox1.

```
Column A              Column B
--------              --------
Girls                 Hair
Boys                  Hair
Veg                   Water
Non-Veg               Water
```

Once I select Girls in combobox1 (retrieve from column 'A' in excel), it should show unique value of 'Hair' from column 'B' instead of twice in excel.

Comment: Column A Column B 
Girls  Hair 
Boys  Hair 
Veg  Water 
Non-Veg  Water

Comment: There is only one value for Girl, why would you need to place it in a combobox?

Comment: It is just an example. I want to add unique values in combox2 from column 'B' once I select Girls from column 'A'

Comment: `1` Create a unique `Collection` from Col B and then transfer that to Combobox

Comment: Can you please help me with coding

Comment: Yes I will but I want you to try it first :) I usually try and avoid giving code in a platter :)

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799590/avoid-duplicate-values-in-collection-from-vb6) will get you started

Answer (score 1):

Here are the basics for that kind of linked choices :

That will implement unique values in ComboBox1 :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    Dic As Object, _
    rCell As Range, _
    Key 'As String

Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
UserForm1.ComboBox1.Clear

For Each rCell In Ws.Range("A2", Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If Not Dic.exists(LCase(rCell.Value)) Then
        Dic.Add LCase(rCell.Value), Nothing
    End If
Next rCell

For Each Key In Dic
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem Key
Next
End Sub
```

'And there is the part that put uniques values in ComboBox2 when it matches the criteria with ComboBox1 :

'**When you change the value of the** `ComboBox1`, it'll launch that code, so you need to **refresh in there the values proposed in** `ComboBox2` with your own tests.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    Dic As Object, _
    rCell As Range, _
    Key 'As String

Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Me.ComboBox2.Clear 'Clear all previously added elements
Me.ComboBox2.Value = vbNullString 'Set active value as an empty string

'------Here is where you need to do your tests-------
For Each rCell In Ws.Range("B2", Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    If rCell.Offset(0, -1) <> Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
    Else
        If Not Dic.exists(LCase(rCell.Value)) Then
            Dic.Add LCase(rCell.Value), Nothing
        End If
    End If
Next rCell

For Each Key In Dic
    UserForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem Key
Next
End Sub
```

And the code for a third combobox :

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
        Dic As Object, _
        rCell As Range, _
        Key 'As String

    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Me.ComboBox3.Clear 'Clear all previously added elements
    Me.ComboBox3.Value = vbNullString 'Set active value as an empty string

    '------Here is where you need to do your tests-------
    For Each rCell In Ws.Range("C2", Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        If rCell.Offset(0, -1) <> Me.ComboBox2.Value And rCell.Offset(0, -2) <> Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
        Else
            If Not Dic.exists(LCase(rCell.Value)) Then
                Dic.Add LCase(rCell.Value), Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

    For Each Key In Dic
        UserForm1.ComboBox3.AddItem Key
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its really works. I want to add the unique values in combobox3 from column 'C' based on the selection from combobox2. What all changes do I need to implement

Comment: I replaced the combobox1.value with combobox2.value and "B2" with "C'" in above code but it is not working. Please assist.

Comment: Please take time to read those links, and get into SO spirit : http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
For another cascading combobox, just take the code in `ComboBox1_Change` and place it into `ComboBox2_Change` and switch  `ComboBox2` to `ComboBox3` and `ComboBox1` to `ComboBox2` and `"B2"` to `"C2"` and `"B"` to `"C"` and it'll work.

**But seriously, go read the links I shared, especially the second one**

Comment: You must have forgot something, try the code I gave you in the edit