# Excel [VBA] find duplicate data and delete the oldest one

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem in MS Excel. I´ve a spreadsheet with data like this:

```
 Name     |     timestamp
 ------------------------
 Smith    | 12.05.2015
 Smith    | 01.01.2015
 Smith    | 10.05.2015
 Simpson  | 14.04.2015
 Simpson  | 10.02.2015
 Simpson  | 21.03.2015
 Simpson  | 02.01.2015
```

The data I´ve is much bigger and komplex and there are duplicates with different timestamps. Now I want to delete the oldes ones and want an output like this:

```
 Name     |     timestamp
 Smith    | 12.05.2015
 Simpson  | 14.04.2015
```

I know how to remove duplicates, but in this case it´s a little bit different. I hope you can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: This will get you started `1` Transfer your data to an array `2` create a unique collection of data in col Name and then loop through the array to get the latest time. `3` Store the output in an array `4` Output the array to the worksheet

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799590/avoid-duplicate-values-in-collection-from-vb6) will get you started

Comment: Is your timestamp formatted as text?

Comment: no, it´s formatted as date

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't sort like a date on my system, possibly because I'm using dd/mm/yyyy and it doesn't see "." periods as a date separator.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need VBA.

In my experience the Excel Remove Duplicates code works to remove the first encountered duplicates in a list.

So sort your data by Name ascending and timestamp descending, then remove the duplicates from the Name field only.

You should be left with the most recent names.

Comment: Incorrect Answer. When you have multiple timestamps, `Remove Duplicates` will not remove any duplicates because there aren't any. Please refer to the sample data in the question. The question says he wants the record with latest timestamp

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I'm sorry but you are wrong. I stated remove duplicates from the Name field **only** not both fields.

Comment: That again is an incorrect way. How would that make a difference? :)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. OP doesn't want just names. He wants the corresponding time stamps as well :) Would recommend re-reading the question

Comment: Apologies, I should have said sort Name Ascending and Date/Time Descending. If you have two columns of data and you select within the Data tab on the ribbon to Remove Duplicates and deselect the second column, then only the duplicates in the first column are removed. Try it with a Name heading in col A and a Time heading in col B; put your name in the cell below the Name heading; enter 0:01 in the cell immediately below the Time heading; drag down a few rows; sort as mentioned; go to Data> Remove Duplicates; **uncheck the Time column** and hit OK.

Comment: Mark. I am sorry but you are wrong. That is again an incorrect way of doing it. Try it yourself with the given sample. Also take a bigger dataset. You will get incorrect results :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout did you try what I suggested? Add numerous Names and timestamps sorted ascending names and descending times. It works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77599/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-mark-fitzgerald).

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of testing, and Range.RemoveDuplicates appears to keep the first entry for each duplicate value (at least in a sorted range, which you're going to use).  Here's my solution:

```
Sub SortAndCondense()
'This subroutine sorts a table by name and secondarily by descending date.  It then removes
'all duplicates in the name column.  By sorting the dates in descending order, only the most
'recent entries for each name are preserved
Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim dateTable As Range
Dim header1 As Range, header2 As Range
Set dateTable = wrkSht.Range("A2:B7") 'insert your actual table range; modify as necessary for column headers
Set header1 = wrkSht.Range("A2")
Set header2 = wrkSht.Range("B2")

'sort the column primarily by name, and secondarily by descending date.  The order in which the names are sorted
'is irrelevant.
dateTable.Sort Key1:=header1, Key2:=header2, Order2:=xlDescending

'remove all duplicate names.  The way remove duplicates works (so far as I can tell) is that it keeps only the
'topmost entry for each duplicate column.
dateTable.RemoveDuplicates 1
End Sub
```